# What are the imports for opengl types?

Tags: eclipse, opengl, import

I can't find the imports anywhere on the internet. Every time I try to use one of the types it just gives me an error, and eclipse doesn't seem to ever suggest to import anything from the opengl libraries (I'm using the lwjgl library and the slick library which contains opengl, although I'm not sure if that would cause eclipse to not suggest imports from it).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why no one just told me, but apparently opengl types aren't used by you in java. Instead of using gluint or something in java, you just use the normal int and opengl takes care of the types for you.